# MYSQL - Timeclock Count Hours In/Out for each day of current week

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my table for my database `timeclock` that records each record of an employee clocking in/out. I am wanting to create a function that returns hours for each day Monday-Sunday of current week.

```
id  user    timeinout           type    function    
1   1   2015-08-05 20:20:32     in         1
2   1   2015-08-05 20:20:56     out        1
3   1   2015-08-05 20:29:25     in         1
4   1   2015-08-05 20:32:04     out        2
5   1   2015-08-05 20:36:28     in         1
6   1   2015-08-05 20:40:00     out        1
7   1   2015-08-06 09:05:39     in         1
```

I know this function is way wrong, but here is where I am. I have never done this before so I am at a real loss and all examples I have tried have failed.

```
function gettimeclockHours($user) {
  include $_SESSION['db'];
  try {
      $sql = "SELECT HOUR(timeinout) as hour, COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM timeclock WHERE user = :user GROUP BY HOUR(timeinout)";
      $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $s->bindValue(':user', $user);
      $s->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
      $error = 'Error.' . $e->getMessage();
      moduleError($error);
      exit();
  }
  $result = $s->fetch();
  return $result;
}
```

The Output example I am looking for is below.

```
Day of Week     Total Time
Monday          1.2 Hours
Tuesday     
Wednesday   
Thursday    
Friday  
Saturday    
Sunday
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

split dates by weekday (Mon, Tue etc.) actually simple question. You can use [DAYNAME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function.

More interesting task is to calculate time when user inside. 
It could be sum(outs_time)-sum(ins_time), but in case, when user come at 23:45 and leave at 00:15 next day it won't work. in this case we need to add additional out at 24:00:00

I would go for following solution:
1. transform time to seconds from beginning of the day ([TIME_TO_SEC()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec)
2. check what the last action is "in" and make a flag in subquery

```
select if(max(if(type = 'in', timeinout, 0)) > max(if(type = 'out', timeinout, 0)), 1,0) // 1 - last type is in, 0 - last type is out
from timeclock t1
```

3. final query with adding 24 hours if last type = "in"

   ```
   select DAYNAME(timeinout) as weekday_name,
   (
     sum(if(type = "out",TIME_TO_SEC(timeinout), 0)) - 
     sum(if(type = "in",TIME_TO_SEC(timeinout), 0)) + 24*60*60*
     (select if(max(if(type = 'in', timeinout, 0)) > max(if(type = 'out', timeinout, 0)), 1,0) // 1 - last type is in, 0 - last type is out
       from timeclock t1 
       where t1.user = t2.user and date(t1.timeinout) = date(t2.timeinout))
   )/60/60 hours
   FROM timeclock t2
   GROUP BY user, date(timeinout)
   ```